# List of Case Class to Json as a Response

Tags: json, scala, playframework, case-class

how to serve `List` of `case class` as a `response`.

i want to give response in the form of json, but can't getting how to convert List of Case Class to Json and Pass to the user as a response

**controller**

```
def process = Action.async { implicit request =>
    try{
     val data= model1.searching("scala")
     Future(Ok(Json.obj("result" -> "1", "data" ->??)))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
      Future(Ok(Json.obj("result" -> "0"))) //exception occured
    }
  }
```

**model**

```
case class Team(name: String, image: String, nMember: BigInt, nYear: BigInt)
object model1{
  def searching(term: String) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      val pinfo = SQL("SELECT name,image, no_member, no_year FROM table_name WHERE name like {term} limit 0,9 ").on("term" -> ("%" + term + "%"))()
      var suggestions = List[Team]()
      if (!(pinfo.isEmpty)) {
        suggestions = pinfo.map {
          row =>
            Team(row[String]("name"), row[String]("image"), row[java.math.BigInteger]("no_member"), row[java.math.BigInteger]("no_year"))
        }.toList
      suggestions
    }
  }
}
```

**error in using "data"->data**

```
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: scala.MatchError: ((result,success),(data,Team(publicBoard(The Best Car Of 2014 in India,28361273218382137,2014,198), Team(the best book,191919199199119,6534,12)))) (of class scala.Tuple2)

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[MatchError: ((result,success),(data,List(Team(The Best Car Of 2014 in India,28361273218382137,2014,198), Team(the best book,191919199199119,6534,12)))) (of class scala.Tuple2)]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
Caused by: scala.MatchError: ((result,success),(data,List(Team(The Best Car Of 2014 in India,28361273218382137,2014,198), Team(the best book,191919199199119,6534,12)))) (of class scala.Tuple2)
    at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$$anonfun$decompose$1.apply(Extraction.scala:82) ~[lift-json_2.10-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$$anonfun$decompose$1.apply(Extraction.scala:82) ~[lift-json_2.10-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:109) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

Comment: how come you have net.liftweb.json in there can you check your imports? it seems the wrong library is being used. it should be going through play.api.libs.json.Json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the serializer for your case class, then the conversion will be done automatically (through implicits)

```
package controllers

import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.Try

object ProcessController extends Controller {
  case class Team(tech: String, nMember: BigInt, Years: Int)

  object Team {
    implicit val bigIntFormat = new Format[BigInt] {
      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[BigInt] = json.validate[String].flatMap { s =>
        Try(BigInt(s)).map(v => JsSuccess(v)).getOrElse(JsError(s"$s is not a number"))
      }

      override def writes(o: BigInt): JsValue = JsString(o.toString)
    }
    implicit val teamformat = Json.format[Team]
  }

  def process = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val data = List(Team("scala", 12, 1), Team("java", 20, 5))
    Future(Ok(Json.obj("result" -> "1", "data" -> data)))
  }
}
```

I have taken the liberty to use Int instead of Integer to take advantage of the default play serializers.

when called the action will generate the following json

```
{
  "result": "1",
  "data": [
    {
      "tech": "scala",
      "nMember": "12",
      "Years": 1
    },
    {
      "tech": "java",
      "nMember": "20",
      "Years": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: getting error `[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: scala.MatchError: ((result,success),(data,List(Team(scala,137,20), Team(java,119,34)))) (of class scala.Tuple2)`

Comment: The code I provided in my answer generates exactly the JSON response I have just added. it ran with play 2.3 and I am confident it would run in play 2.2. Your initial code didn't compile, I assume you only posted an extract of a larger piece of code and the error comes from the missing part of the code. Please post the complete code if you want further help.

Comment: do you have a full stacktrace ? skimming the code I don't see anything causing trouble. how are you consuming the `process` action ?(and the definition of process is missing a `try`statement as such it won't compile)

Comment: `process` is called from route, and i missed `try block` only here.
and also added the error

Comment: I have added the full definition of my working controller. In the exception stack trace, it looks like you have liftweb.json being used for some reason. The code I provided is correct for play-json

Comment: Check for nulls, change it to None.